# Custom Post type taxonomy single templates

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have created a Custom Post type called "Ad" I then have a taxonomy under that called "type" I have added some terms in the Type category called "Radio", "TV", "Print".
 I would like WordPress to use a different `single.php` template for each term. I would like to have a Radio template that is different than the Print template.
I have tried `taxonomy-ad-type-radio.php` I have tried `single-ad-type-radio.php` and every other form of those. Can someone tell me what's the best way to accomplish this?

I have added filters to my `functions.php` file to no avail also. I know I am just missing something very easy. Thanks so much for your help.

```
<?php 

/** Register the post type for the ads **/

add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_ad' );

function register_cpt_ad() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Ads', 'ad' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'ad', 'ad' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'ad' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New ad', 'ad' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit ad', 'ad' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New ad', 'ad' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View ad', 'ad' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Ads', 'ad' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No ads found', 'ad' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No ads found in Trash', 'ad' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent ad:', 'ad' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Ads', 'ad' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'Adbank system',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'excerpt', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'type', 'campaign', 'post_tag' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,     
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    'menu_position' => 3,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'ad', $args );
}

/**Register the taxonomy for the ad types**/
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_type' );

function register_taxonomy_type() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Ad Type', 'type' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Ad Types', 'type' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Ad Type', 'type' ),
        'popular_items' => _x( 'Popular Ad Type', 'type' ),
        'all_items' => _x( 'All Ad Type', 'type' ),
        'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent Ad Types', 'type' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Ad Types:', 'type' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Ad Types', 'type' ),
        'update_item' => _x( 'Update Ad Types', 'type' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Ad Types', 'type' ),
        'new_item_name' => _x( 'New Ad Types', 'type' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate ad type with commas', 'type' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove ad type', 'type' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from the most used ad type', 'type' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Ad Type', 'type' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'type', array('ad'), $args );
}

/**Register the taxonomy for the campaigns**/
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_campaign' );

function register_taxonomy_campaign() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Campaigns', 'campaign' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Campaign', 'campaign' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search campaigns', 'campaign' ),
        'popular_items' => _x( 'Popular campaigns', 'campaign' ),
        'all_items' => _x( 'All campaigns', 'campaign' ),
        'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent Campaign', 'campaign' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Campaign:', 'campaign' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Campaign', 'campaign' ),
        'update_item' => _x( 'Update Campaign', 'campaign' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Campaign', 'campaign' ),
        'new_item_name' => _x( 'New Campaign', 'campaign' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate campaigns with commas', 'campaign' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove campaigns', 'campaign' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from the most used campaigns', 'campaign' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Campaigns', 'campaign' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,

        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'campaign', array('ad'), $args );
}

function query_post_type($query) {
    $post_types = get_post_types();

    if ( is_category() || is_tag()) {

        $post_type = get_query_var('ad');

        if ( $post_type ) {
            $post_type = $post_type;
        } else {
            $post_type = $post_types;
        }

        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);

        return $query;
    }
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');

/* NEW STUFF */

// Register the column
function price_column_register( $columns ) {
$columns['level'] = __( 'User Level', 'my-plugin' );

return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-ad_columns', 'price_column_register' );

// Display the column content
function price_column_display( $column_name, $post_id ) {
if ( 'level' != $column_name )
    return;
$roles = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_members_access_role', true );
if ($roles == 'level1') echo 'level1';
echo 'hello';
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'price_column_display', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Append the terms of multiple taxonomies to the list
 * of classes generated by post_class().
 *
 * @since 2010-07-10
 * @alter 2012-01-06
 */
function mysite_post_class( $classes, $class, $ID ) {

    $taxonomies = array(
        'type',
        'campaign',

    );

    $terms = get_the_terms( (int) $ID, $taxonomies );

    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) )
        return $classes;

    foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $classes ) )
            $classes[] = $term->slug;
    }

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'post_class', 'mysite_post_class', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'tpicker_taxonomies', 'my_tpicker_taxonomies' );
function my_tpicker_taxonomies( $old_taxies) { // Filter taxonomy order

    foreach( array("Categories ", "Campaigns ", "Ad Type " ) as $tax_label) {
        $new_taxies[$tax_label] = $old_taxies[$tax_label];
    }

    return $new_taxies;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think your are missing some concepts or not fully understanding.

1. A taxonomy is a way to group things, ie, posts. The same taxonomy can be used for several post types, so a taxonomy is not under a post.
2. The `single` template files are used for the view of a single post. You can make a different single template for each post type, even for each individual post.
3. The specific template for a term of a taxonomy is `taxonomy-{your_taxonomy}-{term}.php`, in your case, it would be for example `taxonomy-type-radio.php`. This template will show all posts within the term radio of the 'type' taxonomy.

I think what you really want is to use a different `single` template based on the term of the taxonomy "type" associated to a 'Ad' post. I assume **only one term of 'type' taxonomy can be selected per post**. You can use [template_include](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter, or more specifically, the [single_template filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template):

```
<?php
function get_custom_single_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'ad') {
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'type');
        if($terms && !is_wp_error( $terms )) {
            //Make a foreach because $terms is an array but it supposed to be only one term
            foreach($terms as $term){
                $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-'.$term->slug.'.php';
            }
        }
     }
     return $single_template;
}

add_filter( "single_template", "get_custom_single_template" ) ;
?>
```

Put this in the functions.php file of your theme. Don't forget to create the single-*.php for each term (single-radio.php, single-tv.php, etc).

If you don't need a full template file and only need small modifications, like differents CSS classes, you can check if the post has the term and assign a diferrent class. For exmaple, in a common single template:

```
 <div class="<?php echo class="<?php echo has_term( 'radio', 'type' ) ? 'radio' : ''; ?>">
   <?php the_cotent();?>
</div>
```

Or

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'type');
$class = '';
//Make a foreach because $terms is an array but it supposed to be only one term
foreach($terms as $term){
    $class = $term->slug;
}
?>
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
   <?php the_cotent();?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! I want to have a different template for each "type" So if the single post is in the radio category then it pulls the single radio template. Forgive my ignorance but where do I put your code? functions file?

Comment: Yes, in the functions.php file. Also you have to create single-radio.php, single-tv.php and so on ... in your theme folder.

Comment: That is what I thought and I did all this and for some reason it is only pulling from the single-ad.php it refuses to look at any other single-template. Even when I get rid of the single-ad.php it wont look to any other single file. Maybe the theme developer put something in here somewhere to say to only pull from that one. I just cant find it ;-(

Comment: In order to help you further I need to see the code you are using to register the custom post type and the custom taxonomy. Can you edit your question and add the code?

Comment: Can you also try again the code of my answer? I've edited it.

Comment: I just added it all but it made it break in weird places because of the {}'s I hope you can read it ok. Just read it all as one long functions.php  Thanks so much... if you can figure this out you will be my hero!!

Comment: Have you tried again the code of my answer, I edited and asked you to try again but you didn't say if tried or not.

Comment: For some reason that code just gives me a blank white page with nothing on it. It messes up all the single post not only the radio ones.

Comment: Sorry, I have a misspelling. Try again, I've tested and it is working here.

Comment: Jan you are my new best friend!!! it is working great now!!